# CMake cross-platform library linking

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project which uses a lot of external libraries. I use CMake as the build system. Currently, I add and link to the libraries like this:

```
##### LIBRARIES ###############################################

# Try to find the library the "classic" way
find_library("DEPENDENCY_GLFW" NAMES "glfw" "glfw3")

# Try to find a package for the library
find_package(glfw3 CONFIG)

# Check if the library has been found using the "classic" way
if(DEPENDENCY_GLFW MATCHES "NOTFOUND")
    # If it was not found, check if find_package found it
    if(glfw3_FOUND)
        # find_package found it, add target 
        list(APPEND "DEPENDENCIES" "glfw")
        message(STATUS ">> Found dependency: GLEW")
    else()
        # Has not been found
        message(WARNING ">> Unable to find dependency: GLFW")
    endif()
else()
    # Found it with the "classic" way
    list(APPEND "DEPENDENCIES" "${DEPENDENCY_GLFW}")
    message(STATUS ">> Found dependency: GLFW")
endif()

##### HEADERS #################################################

# Find the header path
find_path(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY "GLFW/glfw3.h")
if(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY MATCHES "NOTFOUND")
    # Has not been found
    message(WARNING ">> Unable to find dependency headers: GLFW")
else()
    # Has been found, add directory to list
    list(APPEND "DEPENDENCIES_HEADERS" "${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}")
    message(STATUS ">> Found dependency headers: GLFW")
endif()

# ...

target_include_directories("mytarget" PUBLIC "${DEPENDENCIES_HEADERS}")
target_link_libraries("mytarget" PUBLIC "${DEPENDENCIES}")
```

Although this works, I'm pretty sure that there is a better way to accomplish this.
The code should be as cross-platform as possible, meaning that you should be able to link to the CMake packages provided by `vcpkg` (e.g. on Windows) or just the libraries (e.g. on Linux).

Comment: "Try to find the library the "classic" way" - Eh? The normal way for find the libraries is using `find_package`, both on Windows and Linux. Why do you duplicate its functionslity with plain `find_library`/`find_path`? What exact problem is solved by your code by using these commands?

Comment: Just use modern CMake with IMPORTED targets. Then you can just link to these imported targets.